# OnClick select all text in text_field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, onclick, textfield

is there a rails way to enable a text_field to select all text upon clicking on it? If not how can I enable the JavaScript to add that type of functionality?

```
<% text_field value => "highlight this", :after => "onClick="SelectAll('txtfld');"" %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend reading this article:

[highlight text on click textbox](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/onclick_select_all_text_in_field/)

It is exactly what you want.

```
<% form_for @foo do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :bar, :onclick => 'this.select();' %>
     or
  <%= text_field_tag :bar, nil, :onclick => 'this.select();' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery, this is very easy and convenient.

Add this to your javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".select_all_text").focus(function() {
    this.select();
  });
});
```

After that, add the class name `select_all_text` to the fields you want to have the functionality:

```
<%= f.text_field :test, :class => "select_all_text" %>
```

Comment: will this work if the text field already has a css class style attached to it?

Comment: you can attach multiple css classes. you can only have one id. separate multiple classes via spaces

class="class_one class_two"

Comment: Yes of course. eg. `<%= f.text_field :test, :class => "class1 class2 select_all_text other_class" %>`